# Subviews incorrect size?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Let me start off with saying that I am no expert in iOS Development or Objective-C.

I am making a app for a local charity(its a church) and they want it to support rotation.

The app work as expected if started in portrait mode, I can choose my new subview and the rotate it works perfectly.

However I need it to work so they can rotate at any time. The Main view(the one loaded on startup) already does this out of the box; but my subviews do not.

I have attached 3 screenshots below to try and explain what I mean.

This is how it looks in portrait mode:

[image: The expected result in portait]

In landscape:

[image: In landscape with wrong size]

and back to portrait it I started the app rotated:

[image: In portrait with wrong size]

If it helps I add the subview like this:

```
dailyPrayerView = [[DailyPrayerView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DailyPrayerView" bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:dailyPrayerView.view];
```

Does anybody have any ideas why this is?

Comment: How is your UI built? Is the top level view controller a UINavigationController?

Comment: What version iOS - rotation has changed slightly in iOS6 so this will affect any answers

Answer (score 0):

Check the autoresizing mask in Interface Builder. It's on the sizes pane of the Utilities pane. You should be able to make it stretch to fit the screen, rather than staying at a constant size.

Comment: This didn't fix my problem.